# Blending two layers of text

Tags: css, stylus, mix-blend-mode

I am trying to blend two layers of text on top of each other, where both layers are white, but on the parts where the two words overlaps each other, I want the words to have the same color as the background.

I've started playing around with mix-blend-mode.

It only needs to work in the last version of the browsers (never mind ie)

http://codepen.io/SusanneLundblad/pen/bEopPw?editors=110

```
.wrap
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center

h1,h2
  font-family: 'Limelight', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase

 h1
  font-size: 400px
  color: white
  //mix-blend-mode: overlay
h2
  color: #282828
  position: absolute
  font-size: 200px
  top: 50%
  left: 50%
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
```

If anyone has any suggestions I would be super happy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by making use of svg as background along with the

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
```

property.

Updated: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPGmLo

**Note:** Code only supports webkit browsers.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Except I don't want the background to be black, but almost black :) But thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer. I hope this solves your problem. You may need to use data uri to change the font.